# How are second and third electron affinities of atoms measured?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrons

Wikipedia data page on electron affinities shows second and third electron affinities. Of course, they are negative, because one tries to attach electron to anion. But how are they measured or calculated in practice?

[Electron affinity in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_affinity_(data_page))

Comment: You have an electron rich source and measure the ratios of different charge states.

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you. But i still not clearly undestand it in detail. Could you point to some publications or relevant keywords for search?

Comment: There are spectroscopic methods, which calculates number of atoms ejected of a salt MX (X has -2 oxidation state) is calculated and equilibrium constant between X2- —>X+2e is calculated and then electron affinity. Here is the pdf https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.nrcresearchpress.com/doi/pdf/10.1139/v90-244&ved=2ahUKEwjusJrqzfzeAhUJTI8KHQVkCa0QFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw0zjMhbcHbEDNdiwjvDGVSS

Comment: @SauravSingh Thank you! Could you write this as answer?